# Is it valid to use partition by- order by in view

Tags: t-sql

I am reviewing a view definition which is as below. I could find the information regarding how order by is not honored in view definition unless used with TOP. but not sure if this view would work as intended. This view is expected to give all the employee records that are latest assuming EmpployeeDup has duplicate EmpIDs.

When I tested this seems to work as expected, but I don't think we can rely on this if order by is not guaranteed when used in View definition by sql server.

```
CREATE VIEW Test AS

SELECT * FROM 

(SELECT *

 ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EmpID ORDER BY LastupdateDatetime DESC) as row_num 

FROM  EmpployeeDup) as rows

WHERE row_num = 1

;

GO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question is yes your query will work as expected. "Not honored" is not what happens if you TRY to use an order by in a view without TOP, OFFSET, or FOR XML. You'll get an error an error instead

`The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.`

It pretty clearly tells you what you must do to make the query work.

Comment: I was focusing on "unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified". As this view definition doesn't explicitly use these constructs..

Comment: @nee21 since it's a window function it doesn't apply